# How to make a httprequest body in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I've always done my web services in PHP. Now I'm trying some ASP.NET on a project and I found myself on a tricky situation. I have the following C# code, behaving as a "client"

```
public void sendRequest(string URL, string JSON)
{

    ASCIIEncoding Encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = Encode.GetBytes(JSON);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;


    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    dataStream.Close();


    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;

    var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
    string responseText;
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
         responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    returnRequestTxtBx.Text = responseText;
}
```

Well, now I want to handle on the ASPX.CS side... 
my question is... how do I access the data I sent as a POST?
Is there a way in the "Page_Load" method that I can handle the JSON I sent?

Comment: Throw in some try catch blocks or else you'll be in a world of pain when you least expect it.

Comment: If you aim to create a web API, I suggest you look up ASP.NET Web Api and give it a good read. Very useful stuff... And you might get to like it, too!

Comment: I'll look into it... trying to enter more on the .NET world! Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read post method data on your server side read `HttpContext.Request.Form` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string value=Request.Form["keyName"];
}
```

Or if you want to access row body data simply read: `Request.InputStream`.

And if you want handle Json format consider [Newtonsoft.Json packege](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).